# How to return value from InAppBrowser to Ionic app

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4, inappbrowser, ionic5

We are loading given URL in the inappbrowser from ionic app, which will load HTML form along with one hidden input field.

I am trying to get that hidden field value while tapping submit button using inappbrowser's executeScript method as follow:

```
  browser.executeScript({
      code:
        "var result; document.getElementById('BtnSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(){" +
        "result = document.getElementById('myInput').value;});",
    });
```

In result variable, input value is fetched but need to return that from executeScript into ionic app context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach your response to message event of inappbrowser and then receive it on app side.

The below script is to send postmessage. It has particular format in which it gets passed. Need to create JSON object.

```
browser.executeScript({
code: "document.getElementById('customBackbtn').onclick = function() {\
var message = 'close';\
var messageObj = {message: message};\
var stringifiedMessageObj = JSON.stringify(messageObj);\
webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage('stringifiedMessageObj');\
}"});
```

Then capture the post message from iab back in your app:

```
browser.on('message').subscribe((val)=>{
const postObject:any = val;

//Do whatever you want to with postObject response from inappbrowser

});
```

Comment: Is there any workaround to get the Request parameter or header from the URL loaded in the browser?

Comment: yes, once you have your inAppBrowser instance open then you can executeScript to get the url and use regex operations to get your parametes from query params. If thats what you were looking for. But rather i would suggest that you get the url with parameters as a post response from inappbrowser using above answer and then you can manipulate the object received in angular. It would be easier to handle that way..

Comment: Request parameter is attached as the Form data into URL not query param.. Is it possible to get from inappbrowser?

Comment: @Muthuraja yes it is possible. You need to capture response of window.location.href  as part of executeScript and use post message to pull the string to your angular side to do whatever you want with the string that has got your data. As far as form data is concerned if it comes as a part of service response then I am not sure how we pull that data into our application.

Comment: ok @vishal.  Need to fetch that value from service response... that's my requirement